# Nicely formatted multi-line text in Silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight, text, textbox, multiline

I want to have a multiline text nicely formatted and displayed in silverlight 4.0.
I think, it would be nice to use `TextBox` for that purpose (possibility of adjusting the background color and so forth).

My text would like like the following:

```
First row            aaaaaaa   
Second row           bbbbbbbb  
Third row            53456.00
Fourth row           66
```

Basically, what is the best approach to get nicely formatted text - I want to "first... row" to be aligned left, wheres "aaaa ...." aligned right for each row.

Thanks for the clues and hints!

Cheers

Comment: Can you eloborate on how/why background color would be adjusted and what else specifically would "and so forth" refer to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like you are after an items control, here is a starter:-

```
     <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding YourData}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding RowText}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding RowValue}" Grid.Column="1"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

By TextBox, I assume you mean [RichTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee681613%28VS.95%29.aspx).  You may have some options with it's formatting tags. 
You'll most lilkey best off with the the broad range of layout controls already at your disposal.  From the example, it would appear that the [Grid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) would be your element of choice.